# How to view all the P4 changes shelved by a specific user?

Tags: perforce

Describing my requirement below, just as an example. The main question above in general, can be relevant to much diverse audience under diverse scenarios.

While developing a code, I have a practice of shelving the changes made to the code periodically. For example, if my code intends to achieve 4 different objectives, I shelve my changes each time one of the objective is achieved. That way, if I mess up things while coding for a next objective, I just unshelve the changes from my previously shelved changes. This is a very nice way of cleaning up things.

The problem is when there are large number of shelved changes, it becomes difficult to keep track of all your change-list numbers. In such a case, if there is a single command to retrieve a list all the change-lists shelved by me or any user for that matter, I can do a `p4 describe -s <#CL>`  and get the know what changes does a particular shelved change-list contains. That would definitely help keep things more organised!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The command you need is

`p4 changes -u USERNAME -s shelved`

You can further limit that to a specific workspace etc. (See `p4 help changes` for your options.)